# how to check watch is active connection with iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have checked two ways wcsession.default.isPaired. This was returns true if watch is paired with phone even both are not active. Another is wcsession.default.isReachable this was returns true only after connected and app is in foreground. 
Am using background data transfer from watch. My issue was when background data transfer am checking whether watch is reachable or not. By default watch connectivity session reachable is false on background.
how cum I check watch is connected to phone on background. Is their any function i missed.